# Google Drive API throws 'method not allowed' in the 'get token' function in appcelerator

Tags: android, api

In Google Drive API, I am getting the error `Method not allowed`

This is the code I am using which throws the error:

```
xhr.open("POST", 'http://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    var data = {
        code : code,
        client_id : _opt.clientId,
        client_secret : _opt.clientSecret,
        redirect_uri : 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob',
        grant_type : 'authorization_code'
    };
    // Send the request.
    xhr.send(data);
```

How do I solve this error?